# I am trying to select the last index of a string after splitting an image name from imageJ. I know in python we can do string[-1]

Tags: indexing, imagej, fiji

imageName=getTitle(); #This returns a string with the entire path of where the image is.

image1 = split(imageName,"/"); #splits the image where "/" is. Based on path, this varies in length

image = image1[1]; #I want the last one but it will not always be the nth index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` returns an array. In your example you assign the array to `image1` so you can find the length of the array using `image1.length`. Arrays in ImageJ macro language are 0-based so you need to subtract 1 to find the last element.

```
imageName=getTitle(); #This returns a string with the entire path of where the image is.
image1 = split(imageName,"/"); #splits the image where "/" is. Based on path, this varies in length
image = image1[image1.length - 1]; #last element.
```

Note that splitting using `/` will work on mac but not Windows.

My answer is directed at your indexing question. If you simply want the file name without the path, Take a look at `File.name` and `File.nameWithoutExtension` for more straightforward ways to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You write:
"imageName=getTitle(); #This returns a string with the entire path of where the image is."

This isn't true. "getTitle();" returns the name of the frontmost image including its suffix, not the path!